# Verilog module output is X even when assigned a value

Tags: verilog

I have a simple 8 bit parity checking module to check results and set flags.

The output of this module is always X, and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Here is the code:

```
module parity8 (p, low8);

   output p;
   input [7:0] low8;

   wire [3:0] pchka;
   wire [1:0] pchkb;
   wire parity_bar;

   xor2$ xora0 (pchka[0], low8[0], low8[1]),
         xora1 (pchka[1], low8[2], low8[3]),
         xora2 (pchka[2], low8[4], low8[5]),
         xora3 (pchka[3], low8[6], low8[7]),

         xorb0 (pchkb[0], pchka[0], pchka[1]),
         xorb1 (pchkb[1], pchka[2], pchka[3]), 

         xorp (parity_bar, pchkb[0], pchkb[1]);

   inv1$ pinv (p, parity_bar);

endmodule
```

parity_bar always has the correct value, and I tried making another wire ptest, which replaced p on the last line. Ptest had the correct value, so I tried adding:

```
assign p = ptest;
```

Yet the output of the module was still X. Even tried assigning p = 1'b1; and it didn't change. Hopefully this isn't something obvious, thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like there is another driver on `p`, either from another module or defined as a `reg` in the test-bench. Outputs of sub-modules should be connected to wire types and not have any other drivers.

Comment: That could be it. In the module that's calling parity8, I wasn't sure the best way to initialize my flag vector to 0 (very new to verilog), so I did: 
assign flags = 32'b0;
The reason I thought this wasn't an issue, is that there are other modules that perform similar tasks to calculate a flag, and drive a different bit. They work just fine. Anyway, I'll take out the driver to that bit and let y'all know if it works. Thanks

Comment: Can you also add the testbench code in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greg pointed out, the issue was that p was driving a bit in a bit vector that had been assigned all 0's. I had dismissed this because I have several modules driving bits on this same bit vector. I suppose a problem only occurs if the assignment value and the value produced by the module are not the same.